# Updating external metadata of an ECL item

Tags: web8.5, ecl, sdl-tridion, external-integrations

I can successfully set metadata properties for an ECL item and display it in External Metadata Schema as shown below:
[image: Screenshot of External Metadata Schema]

I am not able to figure out how to read the updated Metadata fields in the ECL code.

The idea is that properties like **Alt Text** can be updated in CME, read in ECL and saved back to external system. But, I am unable to read the updated field values in the following functions:

```
public string MetadataXml
{
    get
    {
        return metadata.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        // set metadata values
    }
}

--OR--

public IContentLibraryItem Save(bool readback)
{
    return readback ? this : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with adding Metdata Schema to the newly created ECL Stub Schema. I am using the Metadata Schema to relate an alternate text information to ECL item. Its getting stored in Tridion and not in ECL.